# Mono C# WinForms -> Serious performance problems when running on Mac OSX

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, macos, mono

I have a question regarding C#, Mono and OSX. I have created a Program in C# using Windows Forms and am trying to make it usable on a Mac.

Problem is, that the performance is extremely poor on OSX and I just can´t find a way to speed it up. The program itself is quite simple actually: A Client Server System using just two DataGridViews, a few ComboBoxes and Buttons, a TabControl, a few SplitContainers - and thats it! Works fine on Windows and has no speed problems whatsoever.

When I open the program on a Mac (MacBook Air, OSX Version 10.8.3) it takes ages to load the GUI. Building it up takes about 0.5sec on WIndows and nearly a Minute on a Mac(!). All the controls are built up very slow and most of the time when interacting with the program by clicking on something it takes another minimum of 10secs to respond.

I´ve learned that Mono natively builds up the GUI using Windows.System.Drawing. Is that a possible reason for the extremely slow response of the program? What can I do to speed up the programm? There must be some way, as Mono would be fairly useless if it´s not even usable for such a simple program...

I have spent hours trying to google an answer to my issue and just can´t find anything usefull: AheadOfTime-Compiling, LLVM - nothing improves the performance.

Thanks a lot for your answers in advance!

Chris

**UPDATE:**
I´ve decreased the perfomance issue a bit now. Mono seems to have problems with the CellFormating of Gridviews. I changed the code in the applicable parts and it´s running faster now.

Nevertheless it still takes ages to build up the GUI. You can literally watch it build the GUI. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Are you using XML to transport the data?

Answer (score 3):

The loading time is likely the JIT compiling your code for the first time (takes my assemblies about 30-60 seconds to boot up the first time too); running your program a second time should load much faster. On Windows, Visual Studio will AOT your assembly as part of the compilation, so the first boot up is fast. The slow control performance I believe is due to the font-rendering (it's not even good looking rendering either). On top of that, [keyboard handling is wrongly implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285438/incorrect-missing-and-duplicate-keypress-events) and since Mountain Lion, you'll also need users to download XQuartz.

Mono is useful, but its WinForms implementation isn't. If OS X support is important to you, your options are as follows:

1. Use a different toolkit (GTK#, WX.Net, etc).
2. Build a `Cocoa Library` DLL using XCode and `PInvoke` it from C#.

The safest bet is the latter, but if your needs are simple, it might be easier to just use a different toolkit.

Comment: Visual Studio does not have an AOT compiler or interact with mscorsvw. What is your source?

Comment: @Dai I believe it invokes [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163808.aspx) (or similar) when compiled in Visual Studio, but I'll try to find you the blog post a little later when I get home.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Thanks for the answer. As the program isn´t that big I could probably use a different toolkit. Do you have any experience with the toolkits you suggested? It would be rather annoying if I swap the toolkit and experience the same speed issue I have now :-)

Comment: @Mr.Smith Running my program more than once doesnt resolve the speed issue. You´re right: The font rendering is not really good, but could it really be the cause of the slow controls? I suspect it might be Mono redrawing all WinForms via Windows.System.Drawing, as it takes ages to build up every single Form. I don´t seem to be the only person experiencing slow performance with WinForms, but in other cases it seems to do the job. Is there anything I could tweek to resolve the issue? The problems I mentioned are based on an already installed XQuartz.

Comment: There's also the possibility of using MonoMac which is a C# binding for the Cocoa APIs (would beat having to write your own).

Comment: @jstedfast Thanks for the answer. I will try that out and post the results. It will take a few days though.

Comment: @Chris Xamarin shoved that library aside in favor of Xamarin's commercial library "Xamarin.Mac". It may not be worth your time investing whether you can use it. :|

Answer (score 1):

You will have to debug on a Mac or Linux to find what exactly is running so poorly. Mono has some implementations that are surprisingly slow. While you see the symptom of slow UI, the cause may be something else entirely.

For example, in a similar situation, I found that XmlDocument was very slow because I was researching why the UI was so sluggish. If you are using XmlDocument to store the data from the server, it could cause your UI to be slow and barely responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using XmlDocument to read the server adress from an xml-file. As I´m only reading an IP adress that can´t really be the issue - or can it? I´ll just hardcode the server adress, recompile to test and post the result here. That might take a few days, as I´m currently resolving other issues. Also, what do I need if I want to debug a program developed in Visual Studio on a mac?

Comment: MonoDevelop is free and has a standard Mac installer.